# iPad application failed to install from iTunes on Windows

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios, windows

I am trying to install an application on my iPad 2 from Windows. Whenever I do so, I am getting an alert on iPad: **Application failed to install**.

When I install the same application from iTunes on my MacBook, everything works fine and the application is successfully installed on the device. I am sure it is not the case of some provisioning profile error. There might be some issue with iTunes or the OS version, but I don't know.

I have iTunes 10.5.5.3 and Windows Vista. Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Nitish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, check to make sure that there is not a download in progress that has not been interrupted/paused.

Secondly, the file may be corrupt, my suggestion would be to remove the .ipa file from windows, and allow iTunes to re-download it.

- right click the app within iTunes and click "Show in Windows Explorer"
- find the .ipa file for your application and delete it.
- re-download the app from your Purchased Apps page in iTunes.

Comment: Do Windows users actually have to drag and drop an IPA downloaded from Purchased Apps just to install an app? Seems unlikely to me. Probably the issue is that OS/X has his iTunes library synced and Windows does not.

Comment: @ithras no, they don't it works just like iTunes under OSX, my instructions are for removing the .ipa from the iTunes storage location so that iTunes Windows is forced to re-download it. Doesn't say anything about drag and droop

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues today when I updated iTunes.  I run Win 7 64 bit and iTunes 10.5.5.3 could not find my iPhone 4S.

I did a System Restore back to the time I installed the update and the system reverted back to iTunes 10.5.2.11.  Everything worked fine again.

I have never had an issue with iTunes updates previously so I either had a corruption or the update has a problem.

Answer (score -1):

May be you are trying to install older version of the app therefore apps will be failed to install try installing updated files (ipa)